# Table field is recording VARCHAR as 0

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form which has 6 fields, Name, Email, Phone, Gender, Industry and Education. The first four field record the values entered correctly in the mysql db, the industry and the education fields just show 0. I've looked everywhere and couldn't find the issue, any help is appreciated.

form:
[image: form]

table structure:
[image: table structure]

table values:
[image: table values]

```
    <?php
$username = $_POST['username'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$gender = $_POST['gender'];
$industry = $_POST['industry'];
$education = $_POST['education'];

if (!empty($username) || !empty($email) || !empty($phone) || !empty($gender) || !empty($industry) || !empty($education)) {

    //create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($host, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbname);
    if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
     die('Connect Error('. mysqli_connect_errno().')'. mysqli_connect_error());
    } else {
     $SELECT = "SELECT email From register Where email = ? Limit 1";
     $INSERT = "INSERT Into register (username, email, phone, gender, industry, education) values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
     //Prepare statement
     $stmt = $conn->prepare($SELECT);
     $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);
     $stmt->execute();
     $stmt->bind_result($email);
     $stmt->store_result();
     $rnum = $stmt->num_rows;
     if ($rnum==0) {
      $stmt->close();
      $stmt = $conn->prepare($INSERT);
      $stmt->bind_param("ssssii", $username, $email, $phone, $gender, $industry, $education);
      $stmt->execute();
      echo "";
     } else {
      echo "Someone already register using this email";
     }
     $stmt->close();
     $conn->close();
    }
} else {
 echo "All field are required";
 die();
}
?>
```

Comment: code please, dont make us guess

Comment: Welcome, Joseph. As talented as we are here on Stack Overflow, we are not psychics. You'll need to share some code and show us what you're trying before anyone can provide proper assistance. "[How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)" can help.

Comment: Just added the code and the screen shots

Comment: `$stmt->bind_param("ssssii", $username, $email, $phone, $gender, $industry, $education);` industry\education are strings not integers

Comment: All the `||` should be `&&`.

Comment: Change `ssssii` to `ssssss`

Comment: But kudos for using parameters in the first place. :)

Comment: Rather than having a `SELECT` to see if the email address exists, make email a UNIQUE KEY in the database.  This removes a race condition (two submissions at the same time). Your insert error will tell you if that already exists.

Answer (score 0):

**syntax:** bind_param ( string $types , mixed &$var1 [, mixed &$... ] )

**$types**
A string that contains one or more characters which specify the types for the corresponding bind variables:

Type specification chars

**i**   corresponding variable has type integer

**d**   corresponding variable has type double

**s**   corresponding variable has type string

**b**   corresponding variable is a blob and will be sent in packets

In your case everything is string so use "ssssss" instead "ssssii"

```
  $stmt->bind_param("ssssss", $username1, $email, $phone, $gender, $industry, $education);
```